# Connectio Faild to Kafka with IBM Info Sphere

Tags: apache-kafka, websphere, ibm-infosphere

While trying to read a Kafka topic in a InfoSpfhere [Job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FmcB.png), I got the error

```
Kafka_Customer: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRebalanceListener
at com.ibm.is.cc.kafka.runtime.KafkaProcessor.validateConfiguration (KafkaProcessor.java: 145)
at com.ibm.is.cc.javastage.connector.CC_JavaAdapter.initializeProcessor (CC_JavaAdapter.java: 1008)
at com.ibm.is.cc.javastage.connector.CC_JavaAdapter.getSerializedData (CC_JavaAdapter.java: 705)


Kafka_Customer: Java runtime exception occurred: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRebalanceListener (com.ibm.is.cc.kafka.runtime.KafkaProcessor::validateConfiguration, file KafkaProcessor.java, line 145)
```

I should add the jar file, which is missing, but where and how can I see which version is nedeed?. I could'n find anything after a lot of googling.

Comment: You will probably need [kafka-client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients)

Answer (score 0):

kafka-clients JAR versions are backwards compatible down to 0.10.2, however I would assume that the Kafka processors should have this, so you may want to reach out to IBM support